# How can I add a message to an exception without losing any information in C#?

Tags: c#, exception

I have the following code:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw new FatalException("An error occurred while trying to load the XSLT file.", ex);
}
```

This unfortunately just swallows up the Exception.  I can fix this by doing the following:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

But I would still like to include the custom message for help with event logging.

How do I add this message to the exception without losing any information?  (stack trace/debug symbols, etc.)

Comment: Add the original exception as an `InnerException` on the `FatalException`?

Comment: It is at the end of `throw new FatalException("message", ex)`.

Comment: Why would you want to do what your showing?  Only catch exceptions you can do something with.  Otherwise let them bubble up.

Comment: @Mark You can do that to add a user-friendly message that can be displayed to the user, and then do the logging on your own. If you have FatalException derive from ApplicationException, you'll be able to easily identify Exceptions that you added messages to versus Exceptions that are thrown anywhere else in the code.

Comment: Yeah, the point of this is basically to have a user-friendly message (for logging purposes), but keep the original information in the Exception (for debugging purposes).

Comment: @krillgar Deriving from `ApplicationException` was the recommended practice in the past, but isn't anymore. That's because some framework exceptions actually derive from that class too.

Comment: @svik Thanks. I thought I had read that recently, but my boss had just told me to do that. I guess he hadn't kept up on that "minor" change in practice. So instead, make your own base Exception class and look for that then.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

If you just need to add information to the original exception, such as a user-readable message or specific details that will be useful to you in tracking down the error but that won't be useful to the end user, you can make use of the Exception's [Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data.aspx) property, which is a key/value pair dictionary.

We use this extensively in order to record information such as the report being executed or file that is being processed so that operations can determine what exactly was happening at the time of the error. The user doesn't need this detail since they are working directly with the cause of the failure.

You could also use this to pass a plain text message that makes sense to the user. The only issue is that you will have to perform some additional work in your logging framework or end-user interface in order to extract the data and make it useful to the consumer.

For example, you could do:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.Data.Add("UserMessage", "An error occurred while trying to load the XSLT file.");
    throw;
}
```

Then in the client-side code, you could test to see if UserMessage exists and, if so, present it to the user instead of the Exception:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.Data.Contains("UserMessage"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Data["UserMessage"].ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even better would be `ex.Data["UserMessage"] += "An error occurred...";` so that if some lower level code already added a message, it would append the extra text to it instead of throwing an [`ArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.add(v=vs.110).aspx#ddueExceptionsToggle)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! This additional data is also automatically added to .NET trace logs, and if you use unique keys and descriptive messages all the way up the try/catch chain, it takes no time at all to hunt down the cause of an error.

Comment: What's the benefit of doing this rather than throwing a new Exception and passing the original in as an innerException as per the accepted answer?

Comment: @ajbeaven: There are multiple benefits: 1) Throwing and catching exceptions can be extremely costly in terms of application performance; 2) Adding structured data to the exception means that you can parse it out and perform additional work, routing, or reporting based on the structured data. If you were to embed the information in an exception, you would have to parse the inner exception to determine whether or not it contained useful information; 3) many people send the exception message to the user or log and encapsulating additional information in the exception would result in bad messages

Comment: I can understand 1. I don't see the benefit of 2, it's just that the parsing will be different. Any good logging or exception handling system would already be recursively print inner exceptions anyway. Regarding 3 - I would have thought that this would be a plus for using the innerException approach - you're really wanting to send "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." to the client?

Comment: It may get into the .NET trace but it doesn't get included in `ToString()`.  That is awkward if you have lots of existing code that stringifies an exception to print it out. Is there a way to arrange for `ToString()` to include all the info, or should I be doing something different to dump out an exception as text?

Comment: IMHO, I would prefer logging the relevant exception details at the level they occur and rethrowing the exception. I see why this may be convenient to do in a lot of cases but also how using exceptions as a chain to communicate the reason for an error can be a bad idea.

Comment: You can write a more generic solution by converting ex.Data to a JSON string (since it's just a dictionary). That way any data in the object will be logged. Example:
```$"Stack Trace:\r\n{exc}\r\n\r\nData:\r\n{System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(exc.Data)}"```

Answer (score 18):

That original Exception is still there.

When you do your Exception logging, the Exception that you receive will be the FatalException that you made with your message. The original Exception is in `ex.InnerException`. You can continue to cycle through InnerException until it's null to get all of the Stack Trace information, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In short, don't.

I'm sure you could find some way of getting around this with some reflection, but I would **strongly** caution you against this. It goes against the original design of exceptions in .NET. Exceptions are not just there to help with logging, they provide information about the original cause of an application failure.

Using the first option is generally preferred as it maintains the stack trace of the original exception but allows you to provide additional information by wrapping it in a separate exception. In my own code, whenever I log exceptions, my logging function will recurse through the InnerException property to find every bit of useful information possible about the error.

Comment: "Logging" may not be the best term to use for this. If you're doing something remote, you could just send an email for specific types of Exceptions when you don't have access to any logging.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs a good answer. The key is to use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException

The you can create a custom object with IDisposable to put all info in it. And if exception happens then FirstChanceException handler gets that info and populate Exception.Data.

Use Local Thread Storage to make it thread safe. Then down the line the code that catches it will get the data and log it.

Example:

```
using(MyCustomMessage.EnterToLocalStorage("Info for logging"") ) 
{ 
...code 
...exception thrown
.... FirstChanceException examines local thread storage and get's "info for logging" and puts into Exception.Data. 
} 
//Dispose is called and all messages that were put into LocalStorage are removed. 
//So if exception was not thrown before then it like nothing happened.
```

Google AsyncDiagnosticStack for a good example. https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncDiagnostics/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncDiagnostics/AsyncDiagnosticStack.cs